# unable to load torchaudio even after installing

Tags: pip, pytorch, torchaudio

[image]

I'm trying to use `torchaudio` but I'm unable to import it. I have installed it and it is also visible through the `pip` list.

```
<ipython-input-6-4cf0a64f61c0> in <module>
----> 1 import torchaudio

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchaudio'
```

```
pytorch-lightning        1.2.0
torch                    1.10.1
torchaudio               0.10.1
torchvision              0.11.2
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.2; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: You should consider upgrading pip via the '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: I dont think that affects the problem. I have updated it and it still is the same

Comment: Do you use windows/linux/mac and do you plan to use GPU or only CPUs ?

Comment: Linux and I currently only have a cpu.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using linux and CPU, you should consider uninstalling every pytorch related packages and re-install them via:

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu
```

as shown [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/).

Comment: It's still giving the same error after your steps.

Comment: Sorry ^^ This fixed my pytorch import issues last time.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same error. Tried a lot of ways to install and use torchaudio.

This was **worked for me** (after *uninstalling existing torchaudio*):

```
import os
!git clone https://github.com/pytorch/audio.git
os.chdir("audio")
!git checkout 632ea67
!python setup.py install
```